# BigQuery in Google Cloud, limiting search of views and cost

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm a little new to BQ, I'm doing a query, very simply of a view to get a quick look at the data, but when I put say LIMIT 100, to see just the first 100 rows, I don't get a reduction in the data required and hence the cost. If I want to simply do this, what can I do that is inexpensive to get the data.

For example:

```
select * from table
```

uses exactly the same projected data as

```
 select * from table limit 100
```

Is there not any simplification under hood. Is BQ searching all rows and then taking the top 100?

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery charging is based on the data queried and unfortunately `limit` does not reduce the volume of data queried.

The following can help:

- using the table preview in the console (this is free if I recall correctly) but does not work on views or some types of attached tables
- reducing the number of columns that are queried
- if your data is partitioned, you can query a specific partition - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables

There is information from Google on this page https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-input